# Best pattern Matching algorithm implemented in Java

Tags: java, regex, matching

I am new to Java . My problem is I have to select the rows of an entire file (Size less than 70MB) to match my pattern (e.g.`<subject> <Predicate> <Object>`). Currently I am using basic string matching algorithm bit it takes time so I want to use "Boyer-Moore algorithm". Is it good to use? Do we have some other better solution? If yes Please let me know and the code also in Java.

Comment: Try to put some sample code so we can suggest improvements

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google returned:

- [BoyerMoore implementation](http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/)
- [Boyer-Moore string search algorithm (Java)](http://en.literateprograms.org/Boyer-Moore_string_search_algorithm_%28Java%29)

Maybe you simply give it a try and see the results.

Answer (score 2):

I did some work on this a long time ago.I found the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm faster than Boyer-Moore.

Answer (score 0):

[JEval](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/) is an advanced library for adding high-performance, mathematical,
Boolean and functional expression parsing and evaluation to your Java applications

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Do you think it will perform better string matching with a big file from its counter part like "Boyer-Moore algorithm"?