# Search for one String within a different String

Tags: java, arrays, string, performance, linked-list

I am having some trouble when I try to compare two strings. 
My first string is a word and my second string are some letters that form my word, or not, for example:

```
String 1, my word: "test"
String 2, my soup: "adhesljdtth"
```

In this case, I got all the characters of both strings, and start to process them, when I found some char that belongs to my word in my soup, I need to remove it from my soup, and go to the next element.

I found some ways to compare it and get the results using: StringBuilder, LinkedList, arrays and so on, all work with small strings, but when I get a string with a million of characters, I got some performance problems. I tried to use Binary Search in this case, but even this is taking so long to process my results.

I am using Array.sort function to sort both of my strings.

And to verify if soup has all the letters to form my word, I am doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordLenght; i++) {
    char key = wordCharList[i];
    int length = soupCharList.size();
    int low = 0;
    int high = length - 1;

    while (low <= high) {

        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        char midVal = soupCharList.get(mid);

        if (midVal < key) {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else if (midVal > key) {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        else if(midVal == key) {
            soupCharList.remove(mid);
            break;
        }
        if(high == -1) {   
            return false;
        }
    }
}
    return true;
}
```

Do you have any ideas how to compare it with a better performance?

Comment: Duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961261/best-pattern-matching-algorithm-implemented-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best pattern Matching algorithm implemented in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961261/best-pattern-matching-algorithm-implemented-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I try to compare two strings

For comparing strings, use `String#compare`. Obviously, you're doing something else, so name it properly.

> I found some ways to compare it and get the results using: StringBuilder, LinkedList, arrays and so on, all work with small strings, but when I get a string with a million of characters

None of these data structures have fast lookup. Use `Set` or `Map` for this.

- When you want to know, if the soup contains all characters from the word, use `Set#containsAll`.
- When you want to know, if the soup contains all characters from the word *with a sufficient number of occurrences*, use a `Map<Character, Integer>`.
- For counting, Guava `Multiset<Character>` is easier to use.

As the number of characters are bounded to a small value, you can use arrays containing the counts. This is not very general, but it's extremely simple and extremely fast:

```
int[] wordCounts = makeCounts(word);
int[] soupCounts = makeCounts(soup);
for (int i=0; i<wordCounts.length; ++i) {
    if (wordCounts[i] > soupCount[i]) return false;
}
return true;

int[] makeCounts(String s) {
    int[] result = new int[Character.MAX_VALUE + 1];
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); ++i) ++result[s.charAt(i)];
    return result;
}
```

As your strings don't use all characters, there are optimizations possible.